# Python datetime.datetime.now shows wrong time inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, printing, sleep

I have this simple code in python 3.7.3 in a beagle bone black

```
import time
import datetime
import sys

while True:
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(date)
    time.sleep(10)
```

which returns

```
2020-05-25 14:18:20.208603
2020-05-25 14:18:30.219415
2020-05-25 14:18:40.229831
2020-05-25 18:21:28.222552
2020-05-25 18:21:38.234207
```

The local time in my country when I printed this was 14:21
The code seems to be randomly alternating between local time 3 minutes behind and another time with the right minutes. I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried with pytz, gmtime, etc and I'm still having the same results.

Comment: Try printing `time.time()` to get more evidence if this is a time zone setting issue

Comment: I've tested the code, and it work as expected (10s between each print). This may be link to your hardware or OS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, as pyOliv says, it's a hardware problem. The microcomputer that I'm using doesn't have an internal clock and relies on the internet to update the time. Restarting systemd-timesyncd services solved it for me.